# How general can a given expression be?

Tags: polynomials

If I had some polynomial $q$ and knew it had a repeated root at $x = a$ for some real $a$, I can write down $q(x) = A(x-a)^2 p(x)$ for some polynomial $p$, and some real $A$. Is this any more or less general than $q(x) = $D$(x-a)^2p(x)$ + $C$ for real $C,D$, what I mean by this is that are all the possible polynomials I get by varying $A$ in the first example the same as the possible polynomials I get by varying $C$ and $D$?
Thank you so much for reading.

Comment: For $C=0$ you get the same polynomials, for $C\neq 0$ you get polynomials that do not have a root at $a$. I don't get your question.

Answer (score 1):

The two forms are not equivalent.

> $q(x) = A(x-a)^2 p(x)$ for some polynomial $p$, and some real $A$

This describes a polynomial $q$ with root $a$ of multiplicity $\ge 2$.

> $q(x) = $D$(x-a)^2p(x)$ + $C$ for real $C,D$

This describes a polynomial $q$ whose derivative $q'$ has $a$ as a root. $a$ is also a root of $q$ iff $C=0$.

Comment: You are a great teacher, also who always helps when I comment to help you to fix the answer, because you are not helping to get answer/comment (up)votes.  I hope you will return to the site soon as a great teacher .

Comment: Thank you for the kind words, @lonestudent. Right, I have been less active lately, but I have not left the site, and I have not closed the door on "returning" at some point.

Comment: Due to homelessness, I cannot be on the site much. I'm overstepping my bounds by bothering you again, but if you have a few minutes here, I'd love for you to guide me. As you know, irreducibility and similar things are not at the school level.  Generally, I always avoid using such terminologies. I wrote an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4797792/460967), but that is beyond my knowledge. Actually, I wouldn't want to embarrass myself by sending this answer to MSE. In this sense, can you give me a little help from your wealth of knowledge to understand how consistent this answer is ?...

Comment: @lonestudent I hope you stay safe, wherever you are, and find all the support to get through. Kudos for sticking to math despite the other trials. It's always been a safe space where we are all equal, and right vs. wrong is not a matter of sway.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice and kind words, for not rejecting my request for help, which was *not* the right request to write in a comment, and for not ignoring my request when I was *really* stuck in my answer while I was writing an answer to learn it myself.  I wish you health, wellness and well-being .  Thank you so much, I learned a lot from you .

Answer (score 0):

$C$ must be $0$ in your second expression in order to  have a root at $x=a$ so there is just one constant. In fact there are none, since you can absorb the original $A$ in the quotient polynomial $p(x)$.

Comment: I am really silly I forgot when $C$ is not $0$ we do not have root at $a$ lol

Comment: @NavBhatthal All mathematicians make occasional mistakes like that. It's an occupational hazard. Do note that you don't need the constant $A$ either.