# Prove that the 3 roots are rational.

Tags: polynomials

> Let $ f $ be a polynomial of degree $ 3 $ and having rational coefficients. Prove that, if there exist two distinct nonzero rational numbers $ a,b $ and two roots $ x_1,y_1 $ of $ f $ such that $ ax_1+by_1 $ is rational, then all roots of $ f $ are rational.

---

Let $f(x)=a_3(x-x_1)(x-y_1)(x-\alpha)$. Notice that if we get $x_1,y_1$ to be rational then $\alpha$ too is rational. Now, assume $x_1$ is irrational, then by the given conditions, we get $y_1$ too is irrational. How do i proceed from here?

Comment: Do you know Vieta's relations? Can you bring the third root into play? Also you can assume $a_3=1$ because dividing through doesn't affect the rationality condition or the roots.

Comment: @MarkBennet I tried with vieta with no progress. However, I'm also not quite sure where do I use the fact about $ax_1+by_1$ being rational.

Comment: For any rationals $c, d$, $f(x)$ has three rational roots if and only if $c f(x - d)$ does. Therefore it is sufficient to prove the statement for the case $f(x) = x^3 + p x + q$, where $p$ and $q$ are rational.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it's given that

$$f(x) = r_3x^3 + r_2x^2 + r_1x + r_0 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

where $r_i$ are all rational and $r_3 \neq 0$. Also, for some non-zero and non-equal rational $a$ and $b$, there's a rational $r_4$ where

$$ax_1 + by_1 = r_4 \;\;\to\;\; y_1 = \frac{r_4 - ax_1}{b} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Since $f(x)$ is an odd-degree polynomial, it has at least one real root. The [complex conjugate root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem) states that if $f(x)$ has any non-real complex roots, they are of the form $d\pm ei$ for real $d$ and $e$. From the first part of \eqref{eq2A}, if one or both of $x_1$ or $y_1$ were these roots, then the LHS would be a non-real complex number. Thus, all $3$ roots must be real.

As [Mark Bennet's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4797237/prove-that-the-3-roots-are-rational#comment10201432_4797237) indicates, WLOG we can have $r_3 = 1$ (since dividing by the leading non-zero coefficient doesn't change the roots), and that [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) should be used. This gives that, if $\alpha$ is the third root, then

$$x_1 + y_1 + \alpha = -r_2 \;\;\to\;\; \alpha = -r_2 - x_1 - y_1 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

$$x_{1}y_{1} + x_{1}\alpha + y_{1}\alpha = r_1 \;\;\to\;\; x_1(y_1 + \alpha) + y_1\alpha = r_1 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

$$x_{1}y_{1}\alpha = -r_0 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

From \eqref{eq2A}, as you've already stated, we have that $x_1$ and $y_1$ are either both rational or irrational. From \eqref{eq3A}, if both are rational, so is $\alpha$, so all $3$ are rational. Thus, assume that both $x_1$ and $y_1$ are irrational.

Using \eqref{eq2A} and \eqref{eq3A} in the second part of \eqref{eq4A} results in

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
x_1(-r_2 - x_1) + \left(\frac{r_4 - ax_1}{b}\right)\left(-r_2 - x_1 - \frac{r_4 - ax_1}{b}\right) & = r_1 \\
b^{2}x_1(-r_2 - x_1) + (r_4 - ax_1)(-br_2 - bx_1 - (r_4 - ax_1)) & = b^{2}r_1 \\
(-b^{2} + ab - a^{2})x_1^{2} + ((2a - b)r_4 + abr_2)x_1 + (-br_{2}r_{4} - r_{4}^{2} - b^{2}r_1) & = 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

This is a quadratic equation with rational coefficients, with the first one being non-zero. Thus, multiplying by the resulting common denominator will convert it into one with integers coefficients. Next, using the quadratic formula, we get that

$$x_1 = c_1 + d_1\sqrt{e_1} \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

where $c_1$ and $d_1$ are rationals, with $d_1 \neq 0$, and $e_1$ is a [square-free integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer) $\gt 1$. Similarly, using \eqref{eq7A} in \eqref{eq2A}, we also have

$$y_1 = c_2 + d_2\sqrt{e_1} \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

where $c_2$ and $d_2$ are rationals, with $d_2 \neq 0$.

Note that \eqref{eq2A} minus $a$ times \eqref{eq3A} gives $(b - a)y_1 - a\alpha = r_4 + ar_2 \;\to\; y_1 = \frac{a\alpha + r_4 + ar_2}{b - a}$. If $\alpha$ were rational, then $y_1$ would also be rational, so $\alpha$ must be irrational. Also, from the RHS of \eqref{eq3A}, along with the results above, we have that

$$\alpha = c_3 + d_3\sqrt{e_1} \tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$

where $c_3$ and $d_3$ are rationals, with $d_3 \neq 0$. Thus, using \eqref{eq7A}, \eqref{eq8A} and \eqref{eq9A} in \eqref{eq3A} we get the coefficient of $\sqrt{e_1}$ must be $0$, i.e.,

$$d_1 + d_2 + d_3 = 0 \;\;\to\;\; d_3 = -d_1 - d_2 \tag{10}\label{eq10A}$$

Similarly, from \eqref{eq2A}, we have

$$ad_1 + bd_2 = 0 \tag{11}\label{eq11A}$$

As [Mark Bennet's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4797482/602049) is possibly alluding to, we can use what's asked about and proven in [The radical conjugate roots theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2444227/602049), e.g., from \eqref{eq7A}, with $x_1 = c_1 + d_1\sqrt{e_1}$ being a root, then $c_1 - d_1\sqrt{e_1}$ is also a root. This can also be seen since, from \eqref{eq1A}, we get $f(x_1) = r_5 + r_6\sqrt{e_1}$ for some rational $r_5$ and $r_6$. Since $x_1$ is a root, we get $r_5 = r_6 = 0$. Note that we then also have $f(c_1 - d_1\sqrt{e_1}) = r_5 - r_6\sqrt{e_1} = 0$. Thus, $c_1 - d_1\sqrt{e_1}$ is another root. However, it can't be $y_1$ since $d_2 = -d_1$ in \eqref{eq11A} gives $a = b$, which isn't allowed. Thus, the other root must be $\alpha$ instead, so $d_3 = -d_1$. However, \eqref{eq10A} then gives that $d_2 = 0$, with \eqref{eq11A} showing that $d_1 = 0$ also, so $d_3 = 0$ as well. Thus, \eqref{eq7A}, \eqref{eq8A} and \eqref{eq9A} give that $x_1$, $y_1$ and $\alpha$ are all rational.

This is a faster and simpler way to finish the solution than what I originally did, as shown below. Nonetheless, for posterity and anybody who's interested, I'm leaving this longer and more convoluted technique here.

---

Next, \eqref{eq11A} minus $a$ times \eqref{eq10A} gives

$$(b - a)d_2 - ad_3 = 0 \;\;\to\;\; d_2 = \left(\frac{a}{b - a}\right)d_3 \tag{12}\label{eq12A}$$

Similarly, we get

$$d_1 = \left(\frac{-b}{b - a}\right)d_3 \tag{13}\label{eq13A}$$

Squaring both sides of the first part of \eqref{eq3A} gives

$$x_1^2 + y_1^2 + \alpha^2 + 2(x_{1}y_{1} + x_{1}\alpha + y_{1}\alpha) = r_2^2 \tag{14}\label{eq14A}$$

Using \eqref{eq4A} shows that $x_1^2 + y_1^2 + \alpha^2$ is rational. Thus, substituting \eqref{eq7A}, \eqref{eq8A} and \eqref{eq9A}, the resulting coefficient of $\sqrt{e_1}$ must be $0$, so by also using \eqref{eq12A} and \eqref{eq13A}, we get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
c_{1}d_{1} + c_{2}d_{2} + c_{3}d_{3} & = 0 \\
c_{1}\left(\frac{-b}{b - a}\right)d_3 + c_2\left(\frac{a}{b - a}\right)d_3 + c_{3}d_{3} & = 0 \\
c_{1}(-b) + c_2(a) + c_3(b - a) & = 0 \\
(-c_{1} + c_{3})b + (c_2 - c_3)a & = 0 \\
(c_3 - c_2)a & = (c_{3} - c_{1})b
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{15}\label{eq15A}$$

Substituting each of the $3$ roots into \eqref{eq1A}, summing the results and collecting the powers of each root, then using that the sum of roots and the sum of the squares of the roots are both rational, we also have the sum of the cubes of the roots (i.e., $x_{1}^3 + y_{1}^3 + \alpha^3$) is rational. Once again, substituting \eqref{eq7A}, \eqref{eq8A} and \eqref{eq9A}, the resulting coefficient of $\sqrt{e_1}$ must be $0$, so along with \eqref{eq10A}, we get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
3c_1^{2}d_1 + 3c_2^{2}d_2 + 3c_3^{2}d_3 + d_1^3 + d_2^3 + d_3^3 & = 0 \\
3c_1^{2}d_1 + 3c_2^{2}d_2 + 3c_3^{2}(-d_1 - d_2) + d_1^3 + d_2^3 + (-d_1 - d_2)^3 & = 0 \\
3d_1(c_1^2 - c_3^2) + 3d_2(c_2^2 - c_3^2) - 3d_{1}^{2}d_{2} - 3d_{1}d_{2}^2 & = 0 \\
(c_1 - c_3)(c_1 + c_3)d_1 + (c_2 - c_3)(c_2 + c_3)d_2 - d_{1}d_{2}(d_1 + d_2) & = 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{16}\label{eq16A}$$

From \eqref{eq10A} in the first line of \eqref{eq15A} gives

$$c_{1}d_{1} + c_{2}d_{2} + c_{3}(-d_1 - d_2) = 0 \;\;\to\;\; (c_1 - c_3)d_1 = (c_3 - c_2)d_2 \tag{17}\label{eq17A}$$

Next, with \eqref{eq17A} and \eqref{eq13A} in \eqref{eq16A},

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(c_3 - c_2)(c_1 + c_3)d_2 + (c_2 - c_3)(c_2 + c_3)d_2 - d_{1}d_{2}(d_1 + d_2) & = 0 \\
(c_3 - c_2)(c_1 + c_3) - (c_3 - c_2)(c_2 + c_3) - d_1(d_1 + d_2) & = 0 \\
(c_3 - c_2)(c_1 + c_3 - c_2 - c_3) & = d_1(d_1 + d_2) \\
(c_3 - c_2)(c_1 - c_2) & = -d_{1}(d_3) \\
(c_3 - c_2)(c_1 - c_2) & = \left(\frac{b}{b - a}\right)d_3^2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{18}\label{eq18A}$$

Multiplying both sides by $a$ and using \eqref{eq15A} gives that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(c_3 - c_2)a(c_1 - c_2) & = \left(\frac{ab}{b - a}\right)d_3^2 \\
(c_3 - c_1)b(c_1 - c_2) & = \left(\frac{ab}{b - a}\right)d_3^2 \\
(c_3 - c_1)(c_1 - c_2) & = \left(\frac{a}{b - a}\right)d_3^2 \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{19}\label{eq19A}$$

Now, \eqref{eq18A} minus \eqref{eq19A} gives

$$(c_3 - c_2 - (c_3 - c_1))(c_1 - c_2) = d_3^2 \;\;\to\;\; (c_1 - c_2)^2 = d_3^2 \;\;\to\;\; c_1 - c_2 = \pm d_3 \tag{20}\label{eq20A}$$

If $c_1 - c_2 = d_3$, then using this in \eqref{eq18A}, and with \eqref{eq13A}, we have

$$(c_3 - c_2)d_3 = \left(\frac{b}{b - a}\right)d_3^2 \;\;\to\;\; c_3 - c_2 = -d_1 \tag{21}\label{eq21A}$$

Similarly, if $c_1 - c_2 = -d_3$, we'd get $c_3 - c_2 = d_1$, so in either case, this results in

$$(c_1 - c_2)(c_3 - c_2) = -d_{1}d_{3} \tag{22}\label{eq22A}$$

For the last time, substituting \eqref{eq7A}, \eqref{eq8A} and \eqref{eq9A} into \eqref{eq5A}, the resulting coefficient of $\sqrt{e_1}$ must be $0$, so along with \eqref{eq10A}, \eqref{eq17A} and \eqref{eq22A}, we get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
c_{1}c_{3}d_{2} + c_{2}c_{3}d_{1} + c_{1}c_{2}d_{3} + d_{1}d_{2}d_{3}e_1 & = 0 \\
c_{1}c_{3}d_{2} + c_{2}c_{3}d_{1} + c_{1}c_{2}(-d_1 - d_2) & = -d_{1}d_{2}d_{3}e_1 \\
c_{2}(c_3 - c_1)d_{1} + c_{1}(c_3 - c_2)d_{2} & = -d_{1}d_{2}d_{3}e_1 \\
c_{2}(-(c_3 - c_2))d_{2} + c_{1}(c_3 - c_2)d_{2} & = -d_{1}d_{2}d_{3}e_1 \\
-c_{2}(c_3 - c_2) + c_{1}(c_3 - c_2) & = -d_{1}d_{3}e_1 \\
(c_{1} - c_{2})(c_3 - c_2) & = -d_{1}d_{3}e_1 \\
-d_{1}d_{3} & = -d_{1}d_{3}e_1 \\
1 & = e_1
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{23}\label{eq23A}$$

This contradicts that $x_1$ and $y_1$ are both irrational. In fact, it explicitly shows from \eqref{eq7A}, \eqref{eq8A} and \eqref{eq9A} that $x_1$, $y_1$ and $\alpha$, i.e., all $3$ roots, are rational.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort. I'm yet to go through all of the answer, also I should probably have mentioned the source, it's from Romania Math Olympiad 2000, Grade 10 P4 although I didn't find any solution of it anywhere else.

Comment: @zaemon_23 You're welcome. Note that I've realized, based to some extent on Mark's answer, that there's a simpler way using that if $c_1 + d_{1}\sqrt{e_1}$ is a root, then so is $c_1 - d_{1}\sqrt{e_1}$. I've added an extra part at the end indicating most of my answer can be avoided using this detail.

Comment: @zaemon_23 I've moved my end paragraph, describing the simpler method, to after my $(11)$ so that people read it before going through the no longer required remainder of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since a full answer has been proposed, here is something simpler.

Note that if $x_1$ and $y_1$ are roots of a rational quadratic $x^2-px+q=0$ then $x+y=p$ is a rational relation between them but has (in the terms of the question) $a=b=1$ and the only rational relations between $x_1$ and $y_1$ would then have $a=b$ (this condition is therefore important).

Since $ax_1+by_1$ is rational (not sure why the subscripts are necessary - they lead to overly complicated notation) we have that $y_1=cx_1+d$ for $c$ and $d$ rational. The conditions give $c\neq 0,-1; d\neq 0$.

By Vieta relations we know that the sum of the roots is rational so that the third root $z_1=ex_1+f$ for $e$ and $f$ rational. Also $e\neq 0$.

Then the product of the roots is rational so that $x_1(cx_1+d)(ex_1+f)=r$ and the sum of the pairs of products of the roots is rational $x_1(cx_1+d)+x_1(ex_1+f)+(cx_1+d)(ex_1+f)=s$ with $r$ and $s$ rational. The first of these is a cubic with rational coefficients (why can it not reduce to a quadratic?). The second of these equations is at most a quadratic for $x_1$ having rational coefficients.

That should give you enough of a start - what can you say about the quadratic?

Comment: The second is definitely a quadratic, if you chase the coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

$\color{#0a0}{\rm \bf{Another \thinspace\thinspace proof \thinspace\thinspace .}}$

---

Let $P(x):=x^3+px^2+qx+r$ where $(p,q,r)\in\mathbb Q^{3}$ and $x,y,z$ be the roots of $P(x)$, then define the rational number $c$ as $c:=ax+by$ or equivalently $n:=x+my$, where $n=\dfrac ca$ and $m=\dfrac ba\in\mathbb Q\setminus \{0,1\}$ .

---

Note that if $x,y\in\mathbb C\setminus \mathbb R$ , then we have $x=\alpha + \beta i$ and $y=\alpha - \beta i$, where $\alpha\in\mathbb R \wedge \beta\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ . This leads to :

$$
\begin{align}n:&=\alpha +\beta i + m \left(\alpha-\beta i\right)\\
&=\small{\alpha(m+1)+i\beta\underbrace{(1-m)}_{\color{#c00}{\thinspace ≠\thinspace 0}}\not\in\mathbb R}\end{align}
$$

which yields a contradiction . Also note that, the case $x\in\mathbb R \wedge y\in\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R$ is trivially impossible . Therefore, we conclude that $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^{2}$ .

---

So if $(x,y)\in\mathbb Q^{2}$, then Vieta's formulas tell $z=-p-x-y\in\mathbb Q$ . Wlog, suppose that $x\in\mathbb Q$ and $y\not\in\mathbb Q$ . Since $c\in\mathbb Q$, then there does *not* exist such $(a,b)\in\mathbb Q^{2}$ in this case too .

---

Finally, the last case is $(x,y)\not\in\mathbb Q^{2}$. We have :

$$
\begin{align}&\begin{cases}x+my=n\\
x+y=-p-z\end{cases}\\\\
\implies &y(m-1)=(n+p)+z\end{align}
$$

which implies $z\not\in\mathbb Q$ . This means that, $P(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q[x]$. Then since $x,y$ are the roots of $P(x)$, we have $P(n-my)=0$, which is a *cubic* equation respect to $y$ . Finally, *without* using any algebraic expansions, we see that putting $y^3=-\left(py^2+qy+r\right)$ in $P(n-my)=0$ leads to the *quadratic* equation with the *rational coefficients* respect to $y$, which contradicts the irreducibility of $P(y)$ and this completes the proof .

---

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not spot the mathematical mistake myself . Please, if possible give me some feedback how can I improve my proof . Thank you .

Comment: (+1) Looks fine to me. The first revision of the answer was a bit more (too?) elliptic, but the central idea is sound.

Comment: @dxiv In answering the question, I am actually as eager to learn as the OP asking the question. Many thank you for your help on this matter. Right, in the first revision I forgot that roots can be complex numbers and realized there were other unclear points.  As far as I understand from your comment, I think the last revision can be considered better, although it may not be clean enough .

Answer (score -1):

So we have WLOG $f(x)$ is monic and $x_1,y_1$ are both irrational.

►If $\alpha$ is irrational then its degree $d(\alpha)$ is $2$ or $3$.

If $d(\alpha)=2$ then $x_1$ or $y_1$ is quadratic conjugate of $\alpha$; let it be $x_1$ so $f(x)=(x^2+rx+s)(x-y_1)$ and $y_1$ is rational. Contradiction.

►►If $d(\alpha)=3$ then $x_1$ and $y_1$ are cubic conjugates of $\alpha$ so $ax_1+by_1$ cannot be rational for all distinct rationals $a,b$.

(In fact one has
$\alpha, x_1, y_1\in\mathbb Q(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is certain
irrrational cubic and
$$x_1=r_1\theta^2+r_2\theta+r_3\\y_1=r_4\theta^2+r_5\theta+r_6$$ where  $r_i;\space\space1\ge i\ge6$ is rational so $ax_1+by_1$ cannot be rational. Contradiction)

.